# JavaScript getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm wondering why something like:

`document.getElementById('partofid'+variable+number)` doesn't work?

Here are samples and [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn3Kn/) link, I want "next" button to remove displayed item and show the next one.

HTML:

```
<div id="div-1"> 1 </div>
<div id="div-2" style="display: none"> 2 </div>
<div id="div-3" style="display: none"> 3 </div>
<div id="div-4" style="display: none"> 4 </div>

<a id="next" href="#">next</a>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 1;
var button = document.getElementById('next');

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+counter);
    currentDiv.remove();
    var nextDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+counter+1);
    alert(nextDiv); // why does it return null
    alert('div-'+counter+1); // while this doesn't?
    nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
    counter++;
},true);
```

Comment: `string + 1 + 1 === string11`

Comment: @adeneo unless of course `var string = '1'` instead of `var string = "string"`

Comment: @gillyspy - then you'd have `111`

Comment: @adeneo yeah i meant to put `var string = 1` meaning the answer would be 3,but then the edit timer ran out.  You were mixing metaphors is my point and now I've ironcially mixed metaphors by saying you were "mixing metaphors"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `parseInt`:

```
var nextDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+parseInt(counter+1,10));
```

The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer.The second arguement is radix which is "base", as in a number system.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn3Kn/2/)

Comment: This seems to work! Any ideas why it does require parseInit when it comes to getElementById but works perfectly fine for alert?

Comment: It works for alert, but you are getting id div-11, but when you try to retrieve element with such an id you get null (because there is no element with id div-11).

Comment: @Asterisk, it doesn't "work" any better for `alert`.  Both evaluate to "div-11". To think that `null` is a less valid response then the alert's "div-11" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This code results in string concatenation. E.g. if counter is 1, then you will get `div-11`

```
'div-'+counter+1
```

This is because addition is resolved from right to left.
Then you try to retrieve element with id `div-11`, but you don't have html element with such an id. That's why the function `getElementById` returns null.

To solve the problem first add counter to 1 and then join it with div, like this     `'div-'+(counter+1)`

Answer (score 2):

What's going on here is Javascript has some strange rules about types and the + operator.

string + anything means convert anything to string, then concatenate them together. So "foo" + "bar" == "foobar"... and "div" + 1 == "div1".

The the next step, addition is done left to right, so "div" + 1 + 1 goes to "div" + 1 == "div1".

"div1" + 1... remember, convert to string then put together, so we get "div1"+ 1 == "div11".

I would put parenthesis around your arithmetic. "div" + (1+1) would do the right hand side thing first, so (1+1) == 2 as you expect, then "div" + 2 == "div2", so that's what you expect.

As to the alert thing, your first one is looking at the result of the element lookup, and the second one is looking at the string itself. So the first is null because the element lookup didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because counter+1 = 11 => id = div-11 is not exist. Try this:

```
var counter = 1;
var button = document.getElementById('next');

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+counter);
    currentDiv.remove();
    var nextDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+Number(counter+1));
    alert(nextDiv); // why does it return null
    alert('div-'+Number(counter+1)); // while this doesn't?
    nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
    counter++;
},true);
```

Answer (score 0):

it does work and does exactly what you asked it to do but since you do not have a `div-11` there is nothing found so the evaluation returns `null`.

if you want `div-2` then simply use [order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to sum the counter to the number:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn3Kn/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function load()
{
var counter = 1;
var button = document.getElementById('next');

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+counter);
    currentDiv.remove();
    var nextDiv = document.getElementById('div-'+(counter+1));
    //alert(nextDiv); // why does it return null
    //alert('div-'+(counter+1)); // while this doesn't?
    nextDiv.style.display = "block";
    counter++;
},true);
}
</script>
</head>


<body onload="load()">
<div id="div-1"> 1 </div>
<div id="div-2" style="display: none"> 2 </div>
<div id="div-3" style="display: none"> 3 </div>
<div id="div-4" style="display: none"> 4 </div>

<a id="next" href="#">next</a>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: 1. Unless you call the javascript function in body onload, there is no element named 'next'. as the html has not been parsed yet.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of returning "null" values by getElementById("").

> **you can use script inside the body instead of head**  it will return the html element.

```js
const m=document.getElementById('one')
const m1=document.getElementById('demo')
console.log(m1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   

</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo">sample text</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```